# How to create own WIDGET for adobe muse?

Tags: web, widget, adobe, muse

How to create own widget for adobe muse? So that I can add my own created widget in library to use it.
What tools & ide required for it? If it can be done in adobe muse only then how?

Answer (score 8):

You can't create complete new widgets for Muse.
You can create embedded HTML/CSS/JS widgets with some UI for users to configure options by using the mucow widgets introduced with Muse 7.0.

The documentation for creating a mucow widget is here:
http://adobe-muse.github.io/MuCowDocs/

If you have questions about building mucow widgets in Muse, the Muse forum is probably the best place to ask:
https://forums.adobe.com/community/muse/adobe_muse_mucow_development